# Clickable cross-references to deduction labels

Tags: cross-referencing, proof-package, bussproofs

I'm using the package [`proof`](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~tatsuta/proof-sty.html) for drawing deductions. The package supports labels. However, I'd like to have clickable cross-references to them. Is this possible? Note that I want the label to be a custom text, not a number. The package doesn't seem to have inbuilt support for cross-references (neither clickable nor non-clickable). Neither does the seemingly more comprehensive [`bussproof`](http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/bussproofs/). Below's an example of intended use:

```
\documentclass{llncs}   %or {article}
\usepackage{proof}      %\infer

\begin{document}

\[
\infer[\mbox{mylabel}]{a : A}{a ~\mbox{exists}}
\]

As %\intendedrefto{mylabel} shows, ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using the `hyperref` package should work, but not with this style of labelling, of course.

Comment: You could make it an answer w/ a MWE

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You can set the reference text yourself, since `\label` uses the current definition of `\@currentlabel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}             

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelthis}[2]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}#2%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\infer[\mbox{\labelthis{ml}{mylabel}}]{a : A}{a ~\mbox{exists}}
\]

As \ref{ml} shows, ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are also using `amsmath`, you need to use `\ltx@label` instead of `\label`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelthis}[2]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{#2}\ltx@label{#1}#2%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you expand on the meaning of `[2]{\def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}#2}`?

Comment: @jaam The macro has two arguments; `#1` is used to set the label, `#2` is the text that you want to be printed by `\ref` (so it's stored in `\@currentlabel`) and also in the formula.

Comment: I unaccepted the answer since I couldn't get the solution to work in my manuscript (my solution works but isn't ideal)

Comment: @jaam Unaccepting, in this case, seems unfair in my opinion.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Well, at least it retained the upvote

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{proof}      %\infer
\usepackage{mathtools}  %\tag   
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}     %\color

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{wha}
\infer[\mbox{mylabel}]{a : A}{a ~\mbox{exists}}
\color{white}{\tag*{mylabel}}
\end{equation}

As \ref{wha} shows, ...

\end{document}
```